# Why can not I increment the primary key automatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created a database using Entity Framework code first. But when the form in Create view posted to (post)Create action, each project object's id always takes 0. Because of this reason Model.State always be false. So I can not save the object of project class to the database. I tried to increment the id using [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]. But still it takes zero.

My error message in the create action(post) is "The projectID field is required."

my Project class :

```
    public class Project
    {
      [Column(Order = 100)]
      [Key]
      [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
      public int projectID { get; set; }


      public string projectName { get; set; }


      public string descriptionProject { get; set; }

      public Project parentProject { get; set; }
    }
```

my ProjectsController :

```
    // GET: Projects/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var projectList = db.Projects.ToList().Select(
            c => new SelectListItem
            {
                Selected = false,
                Text = c.projectName,
                Value = c.projectID.ToString()
            }
            ).ToList();
        ViewData["ProjectList"] = projectList;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "projectID,projectName,descriptionProject,identifier,date")] Project project)
    {

        var projectList = db.Projects.ToList().Select(
            c => new SelectListItem
            {
                Selected = false,
                Text = c.projectName,
                Value = c.projectID.ToString()
            }
            ).ToList();
        ViewData["ProjectList"] = projectList;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Projects.Add(project);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(project);
    }
```

my Create View :

```
    @model BulguTakipSistemiv2.Models.Project

    <h2>Create</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
         @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
         @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
         <form class="form-horizontal">
            <fieldset>
               <legend>Project</legend>

                 <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.projectName, new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label" })

                     <div class="col-lg-10">
                         <p>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.projectName, new { @class = "form-control" })</p>
                         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.projectName)
                     </div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.descriptionProject, new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label" })

                     <div class="col-lg-10">
                         <p>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.descriptionProject, new { @class = "form-control" })</p>
                         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.descriptionProject)
                     </div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.parentProject, new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label" })

                     <div class="col-lg-10">
                         <p>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.projectID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["ProjectList"], " --Select Parent Project--")</p>
                         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.parentProject)
                     </div>
                </div>



                <div class="form-group">
                    <p class="col-lg-12">
                       <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" />
                   </p>
                </div>
         </fieldset>
    </form>
  }
```

Thanks in advance. Additionaly my connection string is below:

```
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-BulguTakipSistemiv2-20140812112012yeni6;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-BulguTakipSistemiv2-20140812112012.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      <add name="DBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=BulguTakipSistemiv2yeni6;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: which dbms do you use?

Comment: The only dbms I know that supports AI is MySQL. It is possible to other dbms by using triggers. What DBMS you are using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB.

Comment: can you check if the "Identity" property is actually set on field "projectID" on the db side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you made the sitting of the primary key value a database responsibilities,after creating the entity and adding it as a data row I mean after (db.SaveChanges();) in the database take it's value and please remove any attribute from your business class

Comment: After I had created my models, I added a nested class in my Project class and than I removed this nested class but I guess to remove this nested class was not enough. Because when I looked my database table there were 2 id.  Maybe because of this reason I got this error. I removed all models and than created again. Now it works. Thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.projectID,
```

into

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.parentProject.projectID,
```

Comment: I had applied this solution before :) but parentProject.projectID returned zero maybe because of my GetProjectSelectionList() method (by the way I added a list of select items to my view model instead of viewBag or view data ) it only works for model.projectID not for model.parentProject.projectID I dont know why. I can take the parent id in project id and than I created parentProjectId attribute in my Project class and assigned the project id to this attribute. Finally I searched a parentProject which has this id and added to the project as a parent project.